# Should adult themes be handled with care?

Tags: discussion

I asked myself, what if a child finds this site through a search for Harry Potter and sees  the question about the beheaded wife of the detective in Se7en. How should we handle this?

Comment: Thanks for both answers. I got into the fear, I had to overthink my posts twice. Your arguments are reasonable. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) prohibits usage of this site for users below the age of 13.

The content of all Stack Exchange sites must be "work safe." That means no explicit imagery or language is allowed on the sites. Beyond that, **the ideas or themes expressed are not expected to be watered down to be consumed by an 8-year old.** That's true of almost any literature, television program, radio program, or news outlet anywhere. Finding age-appropriate content for children — whether that is in literature, television, or web sites — is the responsibility of the parent.

Answer (score 11):

No offense, but this is is *the Internet*.  It isn't the responsibility of SE communities to filter our content to be age-appropriate, it's the responsibility of parents to ensure children use the Internet in an age-appropriate way.

That said, there is a line  of appropriateness (that I don't believe has been crossed yet).  Text descriptions of the events of Se7en are well behind that line (in my opinion at least); stills from that movie could definitely cross it, depending on the scene.  Either way, I definitely don't believe we should be policing content based on age-appropriateness (just for appropriateness to the community as a whole).

Comment: I would go so far to say that not online is it not our responsibility to filter content, it is our responsibility to not filter content. The first is a passive "not my problem"; the second is actively avoiding and removing censorship where it is unnecessary. The network was founded on the whole notion of open ideas and uninhibited knowledge flow.